# Supporting different screen sizes on Android with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Supporting different screen sizes on Android with Jetpack Compose
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgCh2.jpg)
this one ok on myphone

but
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFfM4.jpg)
how you can see its not ok how ican fix this issue
This issue is for different font sizes like if i change size in my phone like xxs,xs x, etc its not support all.
It shoud remain same with all screens.
help me plz